# Setting up 'auths' in ~/.docker/config.json file to pull private docker images

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have my `~/.docker/config.json` file like this:

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "gcr.io": {
      "auth": "b2Fhs74nf9s1d.............1SXowjd71nvg4"
    }
  },
  "credsStore": "desktop",
  "experimental": "disabled",
  "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

I am using the `auth` keyname following the ***Second way*** stated in this [gitlab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determining-your-docker_auth_config-data).

---

The value of `auths[gcr.io][auth]` is a **base64 encoded string** generated using:

```sh
echo -n "<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>" | base64
```

For my username & password, I followed this [gcloud doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#token). Hence, the **base64** generation command was like this:

```sh
echo -n "oauth2accesstoken:$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" | base64
```

---

Now when I run in my local machine:

```sh
docker pull gcr.io/my_gcp_project/my_gcr_image:my_tag
```

I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

#### What am I doing wrong?

---

**Some other things I tried myself**

I tried the **[gcloud auth configure-docker](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker)** method to see what it does to the `auths` field so that I can replicate that. However, all it did was just add `credHelpers["gcr.io"] = "gcloud"` in the json file. So it will use my local machines's creds helper and not any auth credentials. That's not helping my case here as I am looking to make it work by hard-coding the credentials inside the `auths[gcr.io]` field in `~/.docker/config.json` file.

I also tried the "**docker login** with `gcloud auth print-access-token`" method like shown in this [gcloud doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#token) to see what it does to the `auths` field. All it did was add an empty object inside the `config.json` like `auths[gcr.io] = {}` and it had nothing else. I assume my OS is storing something in the system somewhere and using the actual creds from there. But this is not helping my case as I am looking to make it work by hard-coding the credentials inside config.json.

This is what the 2 methods above produced in my `~/.docker/config.json` file.

```json
// ~/.docker/config.json file

{
  "auths": {
    "gcr.io": {}, // <--- this one introduced by `docker login`
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
  },
  "credsStore": "desktop",
  "experimental": "disabled",
  "stackOrchestrator": "swarm",
  "credHelpers": { // <--- this one introduced by `gcloud auth configure-docker`
    "gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
}
```

---

Runtime versions I have been using:

- Google Cloud SDK v341.0.0
- Docker v20.10.5, build 55c4c88

---

Comment: Everything looks as it should be and, though you said don't recommend it, I suggest you do the login once using `gcloud auth configure-docker`. Then you'll be able to analyse the `auth` it'll put in your `config.json` and see what was wrong with your setup.

Comment: Adding to @anemyte's comment: I had similar problems with my docker hub auth yesterday. I logged into the hub with the `docker login` command and looked at the resulting config.json and the name of the repo was not what I expected. I'd been trying `docker.io`, but the actual key was `https://index.docker.io/v1`, which was a total surprise to me. Also remember to decode the auth key once you've done this to see what format is actually being used.

Comment: @anemyte @SoftwareEngineer As a matter of fact, i tried `gcloud auth configure-docker` and it only added entries for credHelper. Did nothing to the the auths attribute. Updated my question's ***Some other things I tried myself*** section.